# Issue with Browser Connectivity to a WebSphere Application Server 6.1

Tags: web-applications, jakarta-ee, internet-explorer-6, websphere

I have a J2EE application compound by three sub-applications, installed on a WebSphere Application Server 6.1

Each sub-application is basically an EAR (EJB 2.1 + WEB + Utility). This application is "optimized" for Internet Explorer 6, it is not functional with any other browser (and making it cross-browser isn't possible right now...)

These sub-applications interacts by a consecutive flow, the 1st one calls the 2nd one and the 2nd one calls the 3rd one. This is done by a submit with POST method.

When this consecutive flow is done for a second time, and the browser displays the first HTML response of the 3rd module, it is unable to receive any further responses from the server (after five minutes, the browser displays "The page cannot be displayed" being internally "ERROR_INTERNET_TIMEOUT"), meaning that the application is unusable, being like that until all of the browser windows are closed and a new browser "process" is opened.

This test was done also on a GlassFish v2.1, but the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, looks like that no one could answer, we managed to resolve it so I will answer it myself if someone else encounters the same issue.

The cause of the issue was a setting on internet explorer, that limits the connections per server, the issue was resolved by applying this registry entries, which increases the connections per server

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]

"MaxConnectionsPer1_0Server"=dword:00000010

"MaxConnectionsPerServer"=dword:00000010